# using Linq to sort a list based on the sum of values in each item

Tags: c#, linq

I have another LINQ calculation question.

I have a list made of class items:

```
List<ProductionClass> Production = new List<ProductionClass>();
Production.Add(new ProductionClass() { Plant = "Plant A", Value1 = 94.4, Value2 = 97.2, Value3 = 71.9, Value4 = 12.8 });
Production.Add(new ProductionClass() { Plant = "Plant B", Value1 = 84.1, Value2 = 95.2, Value3 = 64.8, Value4 = 92.5 });
Production.Add(new ProductionClass() { Plant = "Plant C", Value1 = 43.1, Value2 = 66.3, Value3 = 92.7, Value4 = 84.0 });
Production.Add(new ProductionClass() { Plant = "Plant D", Value1 = 72.6, Value2 = 51.2, Value3 = 87.9, Value4 = 68.1 });
```

I would like to reorder that list but based on the sum of Value1,2,3 or Value1,2,3,4 for each entry in the list.

So I would like to keep the list in its current form with all the separate values so I can iterate through it, however I would like it to be in the calculated order.

Something in the form of:

```
List<ProductionClass> orderedProduction = Production.OrderBy(i => i.Sum(i.Value1 + i.Value2 + i.Value3 + i.Value4)).ToList();
```

So for this example this would be the sorted order:

```
{ Plant = "Plant A", Value1 = 94.4, Value2 = 97.2, Value3 = 71.9, Value4 = 12.8 } // Total = 276.3
{ Plant = "Plant D", Value1 = 72.6, Value2 = 51.2, Value3 = 87.9, Value4 = 68.1 } // Total = 279.8
{ Plant = "Plant C", Value1 = 43.1, Value2 = 66.3, Value3 = 92.7, Value4 = 84.0 } // Total = 286.1
{ Plant = "Plant B", Value1 = 84.1, Value2 = 95.2, Value3 = 64.8, Value4 = 92.5 } // Total = 336.6
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: woudnt it just be `Production.OrderBy(i => i.Value1 + i.Value2 + i.Value3 + i.Value4).ToList()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<ProductionClass> orderedProduction = Production
  .OrderBy(saClass => saClass.Value1 + saClass.Value2 + saClass.Value3 + saClass.Value4)
  .ToList();
```

The `Sum` method is for summing over an IEnumerable.  To get the sum of properties from your class, just add the values with `+`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Amy got there first :)

I would just add that I would have added an extension that provided the sum, then you can reuse the simpler code for subsequent sorts.

```
public static class GetSum
{
    public static double SumOfValues(this ProductionClass item) => 
        item.Value1 + item.Value2 + item.Value3 + item.Value4;
}

public class ProductionClass
{
    public string Plant  { get; set; }
    public double Value1 { get; set; }
    public double Value2 { get; set; }
    public double Value3 { get; set; }
    public double Value4 { get; set; }

}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var Production = new List<ProductionClass>();
        Production.Add(new ProductionClass() { Plant = "Plant A", Value1 = 94.4, Value2 = 97.2, Value3 = 71.9, Value4 = 12.8 });
        Production.Add(new ProductionClass() { Plant = "Plant B", Value1 = 84.1, Value2 = 95.2, Value3 = 64.8, Value4 = 92.5 });
        Production.Add(new ProductionClass() { Plant = "Plant C", Value1 = 43.1, Value2 = 66.3, Value3 = 92.7, Value4 = 84.0 });
        Production.Add(new ProductionClass() { Plant = "Plant D", Value1 = 72.6, Value2 = 51.2, Value3 = 87.9, Value4 = 68.1 });

        List<ProductionClass> orderedProduction = Production.OrderBy(row => row.SumOfValues()).ToList<ProductionClass>();

        foreach(ProductionClass item in orderedProduction)
            Console.WriteLine($" {item.Plant} {item.SumOfValues()}");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```